# Django makemigrations does not create models by order in models.py

Tags: django, django-models, model, django-migrations, makemigrations

I have a question about the order in which tables are created in a migration. As there is a `ForeignKey` in model B to connect to model A, I create models with order of A, B and C in models.py. Then:

```
python manage.py makemigrations app
```

There is the migration file generated to create all the models, but the order is:

```
- Create model B
- Create model C
- Create model A
- Add field a_name to b.
```

As the order in models.py really matters, but why doesn't `makemigrations` follow the given order?

Comment: Why does the order matter in your models.py? Is that still relevant in the migration files?

Comment: @knbk, as I use the ForeignKey in the model B, so model A should be created before B. Though I read some doc that  app. A can be used in model B to avoid the order issue, but here I keep to create the model in the right order in models.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order in which you place your models in your models.py matters if and only if one of them references another as a `ForeignKey`. In such a situation the order is important and you will find the the migration does preserve the order.

What's really important is not what shows up when you do m`anage.py makemigrations` but what happens when you do `manage.py migrate` there django usually figures out the correct order. If at anytime you feel that you want to control the order in which tables are created, you are free to edit the migration file (even though this is not really needed)

Comment: yes, I do have ForeignKey used, that is why I control the model order in models.py. But the auto - generated migration file dose not follow the order. So that is a normal case, right? For me, it is just a little bit confusing. I expect to only see "-create the model", but not like "-create the model -add field to the model", this is like create and modify a table.

Comment: Ah, I see, I know that the migrations can be modified, but as you said, will not do that if it is really needed. Thanks very much for the explanation.

Comment: Hi, as I also need to control the order of the columns when created the table in the database, but the manage.py makemigrations dose not reserve the order when a column is a ForeignKey column, so I modified the migration file. I really hope the migration file has the models and the columns follow the order from the models.py, but seems it dose not.

Comment: that really is a completely different question and nothing to do with this one shall we post another question for it?

Comment: Hi, I did not post another question yet, as I manually modified the migration file as a work around. I think the question here is related to that question. As I mentioned that only the ForeignKey columns did not generated as the order of the models.py. And I already accept your answers as correct last week.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I did mistake vote up and correct, still in a Monday sleeping mode :)